# Invalid value of sonar.sources for project:myproject with org.sonarsource.scanner.maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

When i try to launch sonar on jenkins i have the following error :

```
Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project project.pom: 
The folder '/path/to/file/project.core/pom.xml' does not exist for 'project:project.core' 
(base directory = /path/to/folder/project.core) -> [Help 1]
```

I think it's because sonarsource is seeking for a folder and the path locates a pom.xml file but i dont understand why.

My maven project have the following file tree :

```
project.pom
   pom.xml
   project.core
      pom.xml
   project.backend
      pom.xml
  ....
```

Edit : root pom.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>project</groupId>
  <artifactId>project.pom</artifactId>
  <version>X.Y.Z</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>My project</name>
  <description>My project</description>
  <prerequisites>
    <maven>${maven.version.min}</maven>
  </prerequisites>
  <modules>
    <module>project.core</module>
    <module>project.backend</module>
  </modules>
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      //repositories
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      //repositories
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>project</groupId>
        <artifactId>project.core</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>project</groupId>
        <artifactId>project.backend</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What is your version of your SonarQube server?

Answer (score 0):

Maven used to build using pom.xml and it identifies the source and test file according to the predefined structure of the project. In that case, you have to mention the file path explicitly.

Can you please provide your pom.xml that is on your root folder of your project?

Comment: I added it to my main post

Comment: From which folder are you executing the command? If it is project.core then might be it need to be changed.